# Fine tune conditions on steps of a drone pipeline

Tags: drone.io

I have a very basic `.drone.yml` file:

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
  - name: build-testing-docker
    image: my-docker-repo/my-docker-image:latest
    when:
      event: pull_request
```

and I'm trying to understand what are the possible configurations of the `when` section. In was unable to find something in the official documentation. Where can I find the API of this part of the ymal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed, this could be better documented.

It appears that the valid values are:

- push
- pull_request
- tag
- promote (only in newer versions of Drone)
- rollback (only in newer versions of Drone)
- deployment (only in older versions of Drone)

... or any combination of the preceding using yaml array syntax (e.g. `event: [push, tag]`).

Source for newer version of Drone:
https://docker-runner.docs.drone.io/configuration/conditions/
Skip to the 'By Event' heading approx 1/3 of the way down the page.

Source for older version of Drone:
https://0-8-0.docs.drone.io/step-conditions/
Skip to the 'Events' heading approx 1/3 of the way down the page, and note the final example, "Execute a step for all build events", which implicitly is telling us the full set of valid values.

Comment: Good point - I've updated the answer to include the changes in more recent versions of Drone.